# BASH array of variable elements: how to print name of variable

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash array comprised of names of files, say:

```
foo = "foo.file"
bar = "bar.file"
declare -a foobar=( $foo $bar )
```

foo and bar are organized in a directory structure as subdirectories:

```
/maindirectory/foo/foo.file
/maindirectory/bar/bar.file
```

I would like to loop through the array, generating link targets to the complete path, for example:

```
maindirectory="/maindirectory/"
target = $maindirectory(something referential to the name of the variable here)$foo
link = foo
ln -s target link
```

So the goal is to encode the path (and name of the link) as the variable name and the name of the file as the value of the variable.

currently I do this in a harder-to-keep-track-of-way in which I have two arrays declared: one with the path to the file and the other with the names of links. I can loop through:

```
 for ((i=0; i<${#foobarname[@]}; i++)); do
    link=$workingdirectory${foobarname[i]};
    target=$maindirectory${foobarpath[i]};
    ln -s "$target" "$link";
 done
```

but as I said before, I would rather do this with only one array.

Is there a way to encode an array of variable elements, and then spit out the name of the variable element instead of the value of the variable element?

Comment: Sounds impractical, why do you need this?

Comment: this approach reduces the need to update many fields by hand and reduces the rate of error. We're talking about a very large number of files.

Comment: `declare -A foobar=( [foo.file]=/maindirectory/foo/foo.file )` ?

Comment: Or perhaps `declare -A foobar=( [foo]=foo.file [bar]=bar.file )`

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong in `$maindirectory/foo/`? Or just `declare -a foobar=( foo/$foo bar/$bar )` ?

Comment: Is there some regular relation between the file name or file path of the original files and the intended names of the softlinks? If so you can also use a `find | sed | while read line; do ln -s ; done` pattern to achieve this. The simplest case would even be: `find maindir -name '*.file' | while read line; do ln -s "$line" "workingdir/${line%.file}"; do`

Comment: @RutherfordHayes, once a variable has been expanded by the shell, there is no magic way to rediscover *which* variable that text came from. Using an **associative** array is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If every file X.file is in folder X, you can use ${X%.file}/$X to find the full path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even if we store the file paths to variables, you still need instruct bash which variables to loop through, right?   Thus, you need a list of variables.

I am not quite sure this is what you want, but, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

maindirectory="/MyFolder"

foo=file1
bar=file2
foobar=file3
barfoo=file4

# need a list so that we can loop thru
namelist="foo bar foobar barfoo"

for link in $namelist; do
    file=`eval echo \\$$link`
    target=$maindirectory/$link/$file
    echo ln -s $target $link
done
```

It's a test code. When you have done the test, remove `echo`, so that it does the real task to do a symbolic link.

Or, if your file name is exactly the same as its variable, except for the extension ".file", there is a more simpler version:

```
#!/bin/bash

maindirectory="/MyFolder"

for link in "foo bar foobar barfoo"; do
    target=$maindirectory/${link}/${link}.file
    echo ln -s $target $link
done
```